# Copy and paste hyperlink from Excel to Outlook body

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, hyperlink

I have an Excel spreadsheet which contains information about equipment on loan: name, email address, description, hyperlink to the loan document, date of loan, etc.

I have VBA code which runs through the sheet, checking for loan date, and if the return date is within 7 days of return, automatically emails the 'loanee' with the details pulled from the sheet.

Once an email is sent, it then updates the sheet with details of when the email was sent. All is working, apart from the hyperlink to their document.

All I get is the text from the cell.

```vb
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Worksheets("Tracker").Select

    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim lLastRow As Long
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim sSendCC As String
    Dim sSubject As String
    Dim sTemp As String
    Dim strBody As String
    Dim Sigstring As String
    Dim Signature As String
    Dim sURL As String
    
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    OutApp.Session.Logon
    
    sSendCC = Range("D3").Value
    sSubject = "You are within 7 days of the deadline"
    Sigstring = Environ("appdata") & _
                "\Microsoft\Signatures\Mike.htm"
    If Dir(Sigstring) <> "" Then
        Signature = GetBoiler(Sigstring)
    Else
        Signature = ""
    End If
    
    lLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row
    For lRow = 7 To lLastRow
        sURL = Cells(lRow, 5).Value
        If Not IsEmpty(Cells(lRow, 3)) Then
            If Cells(lRow, 8) <> "YES" Then
                If Cells(lRow, 7) <= Now() + 7 Then
                    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
                    
                    strBody = "Hello " & Cells(lRow, 2) & "," & "<br><br>" & _
                                "You have previously signed  the loan of equipment from my department." & "<br><br>" & _
                                "You are within 7 days of the agreement validity and are required to take action to amend." & "<br><br>" & _
                                "Description of loan:  " & Cells(lRow, 4).Value & "<br><br>" & _
                                "Hyperlink:  " & Cells(lRow, 5) & "<br><br>" & _
                                "Please return the item/s or renew the loan agreement (at the above hyperlink) at your earliest convenience.<br><br>"
                    
                    With OutMail
                        .Display
                    End With
                    On Error Resume Next
                    With OutMail
                        .To = Cells(lRow, 3)
                        If sSendCC > "" Then .CC = sSendCC
                        .Subject = sSubject
                        .HTMLBody = "<html><body>" & strBody & Signature
                        SendKeys ("^{ENTER}")
                    End With
                Set OutMail = Nothing
                Cells(lRow, 8) = "YES"
                Cells(lRow, 9) = "E-mail sent on: " & Now()
                End If
                    
            End If
        End If
        
    Next lRow
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you post the code that you have so that we can see what you're doing and try to help?

Comment: Please add an extract of your code, including that part, where you insert the hyperlink to the document for a better understanding, what and how you try to send.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a `<a href="[SOME_URL_ADDRESS]">[Some_Hyperlink_Text]</a>` tag in your code.

try this modified bit of your code

```
sURL = Cells(lRow),5).Hyperlinks(1).Address

            strBody = "Hello " & Cells(lRow, 2) & "," & "<br><br>" & _
                        "You have previously signed  the loan of equipment from my department." & "<br><br>" & _
                        "You are within 7 days of the agreement validity and are required to take action to amend." & "<br><br>" & _
                        "Description of loan:  " & Cells(lRow, 4).Value & "<br><br>" & _
                        "Hyperlink:   <a href=""" & sURL & """>'Insert Hyperlink Text Here'</a><br><br>" & _
                        "Please return the item/s or renew the loan agreement (at the above hyperlink) at your earliest convenience.<br><br>"
```

In the above code that I have modified, I am assuming that `Cells(lRow, 5).value` (`sURL` variable) is a URL (not a in worksheet hyperlink). If it is a worksheet hyperlink, then you might need to extract the link.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Irwin. This almost worked! I have a hyperlink within my email body now, with the option to ctrl+click to open. However, the hyperlink address in the email is not correct.The issue is in the worksheet, the hyperlink cell only displays the text of the hyperlink name, not the address. So the sURL translates the cell text as an address, instead of the actual address. I guess this could be fixed by having the address of the doc in the worksheet, but just won't look as slick...

Comment: Change the `sURL` variable to match the above edit changes.

Comment: Irwin thank you! That worked a treat. Cant tell you how long I've spent trying to figure this out on my own. As a bit of an extra, this code did send the email automatically (I used Sendkeys as .send never seemed to work) but every now and again it displays but doesn't send, any idea what may cause this?

Comment: Get rid of the `SendKeys ("^{ENTER}")` and after the `End With` place the following bit, and test again... `Outmail.Send` ---Personally, I only use the `.Display` method (unless generated a 100+ emails) I have seen vba screw up emails before (if not programmed properly).

Comment: Irvin, thanks again for the follow up. I followed your direction but I'm still having issues with the auto sending, but now another bug has raised its grimy mitt. If the hyperlink cell is empty, I receive a 'runtime error 9 Subscript out of range'. How do I get it to ignore an empty cell?

Comment: ...would it be another If statement? Or is there a simpler way?

Comment: Have an answer to my own question here, so thought I'd update. To solve the runtime error I simply moved the  sURL = Cells(lRow, 5).Value  statement to after  Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0) . Seems to have done the trick.

Comment: Hey Michael, when it comes to other bugs that pop up. I would suggest posting in another question. As i say that, in regards to skipping a blank cell, you could simply use `On Error Resume Next`

Comment: Thanks Irwin, all help gratefully appreciated.